# CSS Problem in scrollbar coloring

Tags: html, css, class, colors, scrollbar

.body_c {
 scrollbar-face-color:#408bc4;
 scrollbar-shadow-color:#afefff;
 scrollbar-highlight-color:#afefff;
 scrollbar-3dlight-color:#000000;
 scrollbar-darkshadow-color:#006399;
 scrollbar-track-color:#bfd3e6;
 scrollbar-arrow-color:#FFFFFF;
 margin-top:0;
 margin-left:0;
 margin-right:0;
}

I am using this  class for coloring scrollbar but it execute only with IE.
Have any solution for color scrollbar in all browsers ?

Comment: nope IE only because it is no w3c standard

Answer (score 5):

You can do a similar thing in Webkit browsers with [different rules](http://webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/). None of this is officially part of CSS though and other browsers don't support anything like it, AFAIK.

First and foremost though, consider **not messing with standard GUI elements**. Scrollbars, buttons etc. should look the same across all websites and applications. It's a basic usability rule.

Answer (score 2):

If you *must* change the appearance of your scrollbars, note that only IE and Webkit browsers support CSSscrollbar changing, but here is a JS plugin that will change the scrollbars in all browsers

[jScrollPane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html).

But usually it's not a great idea as it might confuse your users and elements like this should be the same in all browsers.

Hope that helps.